# If X ~ Bin(2, 1/2) and Y ~ Bin(3,1/3), then find P(2X+3Y=13)

Tags: self-study, binomial-distribution

The 2 random variables have different parameters p, therefore cannot be added. I understand that
2X ~ Bin(4,1/2) and 3Y ~ Bin(9,1/3) [by additive property of binomial distribution with same parameter p].
Now, I have summed all the probabilities where 2X+3Y=13 [for example when 2X=1 and 3Y=12].
However, this is a very long process, and I am not sure how to transform this.
Is there a shorter way to approach this?

Comment: Almost all possibilities should have had a probability of zero. You only need to consider a single case for $X$ and $Y$. Which one?

Comment: Without solving, how do I know which single case to consider?

Comment: What values can $X$ and $Y$ take with positive probability?

Comment: The combinations exist only when r=4 (r is the range of all summations). I got it, thanks

Comment: With this approach, the answer comes out to be  \frac{2^4}{3^9}, but the answer is supposed to be \frac{1}{108}

Comment: I don't quite understand [this comment of yours](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/639711/if-x-bin2-1-2-and-y-bin3-1-3-then-find-p2x3y-13?noredirect=1#comment1195894_639711). Which combination of $X$ and $Y$ values is the only one to contribute a positive probability?

Comment: The combination where $2X$=4 and $3Y$=9

Comment: Correct. Why not $2X=5$ and $3Y=8$? And what is the probability that $2X=4$ and $3Y=9$?

Comment: Since $2X$ follows bin(4,0.5), $2X$ cannot be 5 (we cannot have 5 outcomes when total possibilities are 4 only). In a similar fashion, we eliminate other combinations except for the one used.
When $2X$ = 4 and $3Y$ = 9, the probability is $\frac{1}{2^4}$ * $\frac{1}{3^9}$ = $\frac{1}{314928}$

Comment: Almost correct. $2X$ does not follow a binomial distribution (it cannot take the value 3 with positive probability). But we don't need to look at $2X$ and $3Y$, just look at $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: When $X$ = 2 and $Y$ = 3. we get the answer. 
However, I don't understand why $2X$ does not follow binomial.
$X$ ~ bin(2,0.5), $2X$ just means $X$ + $X$, since parameter p is same, shouldn't we be able to add them and obtain $2X$ ~ bin (4,0.5), as per additive property of binomial distribution?

Comment: $2X$ is not the same as adding two independent and identically distributed binomials! Essentially you are adding two *copies* of $X$, which are perfectly correlated. And therefore $2X$ is a random variable that can only take values 0, 2 or 4, not 1 or 3, so it cannot be binomial.

Comment: Okay, I understood where I was wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

$$X \sim \text{Bin}\left(2, \frac{1}{2}\right)$$ This means $X$ can take on values $0, 1, 2$ with probabilities following the binomial distribution formula $$P(X=k) = \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$ where $n=2$ and $p=\frac{1}{2}$.

$$Y \sim \text{Bin}\left(3, \frac{1}{3}\right)$$ This means $Y$ can take on values $0, 1, 2, 3$ with probabilities following the binomial distribution formula $$P(Y=k) = \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$ where $n=3$ and $p=\frac{1}{3}$.

We need to find $$P(2X+3Y=13)$$

To start, we identify the combinations of $X$ and $Y$ that satisfy the equation $$2X+3Y=13.$$

**Step 1: Identify Possible Combinations**

Given the constraint $2X+3Y=13$, we solve for possible integer solutions for $X$ and $Y$

However, by inspection, we can quickly identify possible combinations because the range of $X$ and $Y$ is limited. Given the equation, $X$ and $Y$ must be in their respective ranges, and the equation $2X+3Y=13$ narrows down the possible combinations significantly. In fact, given the constraints, let's manually calculate:

- For $X=0$, the equation becomes $3Y=13$, which has no integer solution for $Y$. Also, $Y$ only takes $0,1,2,3$
- For $X=1$, the equation becomes $2+3Y=13$ or $3Y=11$, which also has no integer solution for $Y$. Also, $Y$ only takes $0,1,2,3$
- For $X=2$, the equation becomes $4+3Y=13$ or $3Y=9$, which gives $Y=3$.

**Step 2: Calculate Probabilities**

- The probability of $X=2$ is given by $$P(X=2)= \binom{2}{2} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \left(1 - \frac{1}{2}\right)^{2-2} = 1 \cdot \frac{1}{4} \cdot 1 = \frac{1}{4}$$
- The probability of $Y=3$ is given by $$P(Y=3)= \binom{3}{3} \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^3 \left(1 - \frac{1}{3}\right)^{3-3} = 1 \cdot \frac{1}{27} \cdot 1 = \frac{1}{27}$$

**Step 3: Combine the Probabilities**

Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, the combined probability of $$2X+3Y=13$$ with $X=2$ and $Y=3$ is the product of their individual probabilities:

$$P(2X+3Y=13) = P(X=2) \cdot P(Y=3) = \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{27}$$